# How can I convert Markdown to HTML using react-markdown, and export it as HTML code?

Tags: reactjs, markdown, react-markdown

I'm trying to export HTML generated from Markdown text. ReactMarkdown component here converts html but I don't know how to export it so that the user can actually see html code that they can copy.

Frist box is textarea that takes markdown.
The second box renders html, and
the third box shows raw html code.

`# This is a header`

`and some **bold** text`

```
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'


function App() {
  const [markdown, setMarkdown] =useState('')
  // `# This is a header
  // and some **bold** text`

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setMarkdown(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <textarea placeholder='Enter your markdown text' className="textarea" input={markdown} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)} />
       <ReactMarkdown className='reactMarkdownBox'  children={markdown} />
       <div className="htmlbox">How can I export HTML here?</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do is to add a class on `react-markdown`

```
<ReactMarkdown children={markdown} className="react-markdown-test" />
```

[`CODESANDBOX DEMO`](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-bird-6gxbll?file=/src/App.js)

and then get its `innerHTML` as

```
useEffect(() => {
    const el = document.querySelector('.react-markdown-test');
    if (el) {
        const mdHTML = el.innerHTML;
        setHtml(mdHTML);
    }
}, [markdown]);
```

Comment: is there any way to convert html to markdown using this or any other lib in react?